# SharePoint with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition (max 1GB RAM)

Tags: sql-server

I am planning to launch a light-weight app on a dedicated virtual sharepoint
- Windows Server Web Edition 2008
- SQL Server Express Edition 2008 R2
- SharePoint Foundation 2010

When the 1GB RAM limitation starts to affect the usage and how (with what # of requests per minute etc)? How much SQL RAM a single SP site uses when, say, users do not manage documents but load light-weight wiki pages (and use a custom app which does not so sql queries)?